# How to set TortoiseHG to work with Caja on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, mate, mercurial, caja

It is known that modern Ubuntu versions such as Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has corresponding [`tortoisehg-caja` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=tortoisehg-caja). The TortoiseHG package provides GUI for Mercurial.

This results in nice looking item in drop-down menu:

[image: TortoiseHG-Caja in 18.04 LTS]

But old Ubuntu 16.04 LTS does not have such package.

Is it possible to have TortoiseHG integration into Caja file-manager on 16.04 LTS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible because of the fact that Caja integration is already included into Python-extension (see my [patch from 2014 year](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/commits/4b1c546aef38ee4c561ac1a3634aa5b7aa04667a)) and [current version of `nautilus-thg.py` file](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/src/34cc0899fdbf0c30f69af83d506d188ad7b0f914/contrib/nautilus-thg.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

So we need to install `tortoisehg-nautilus` and copy extension from it to home folder, install Python Caja extension and then remove `tortoisehg-nautilus` package:

```
sudo apt-get install tortoisehg-nautilus caja-extensions-common python-caja

mkdir -p ~/.local/share/caja-python/extensions
cp /usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/nautilus-thg.py ~/.local/share/caja-python/extensions/caja-thg.py

sudo apt-get purge tortoisehg-nautilus
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install tortoisehg mercurial
```

restart Caja with `caja -q` and enjoy.