# Is it possible to simultaneously use TortoiseHG (for Mercurial) and RabbitVCS (for Git) in Caja with Cyrillic file-names?

Tags: mate, git, rabbitvcs, mercurial, caja

I run Ubuntu MATE 16.04.6 LTS with Caja file-manager.

I have added TortoiseHG python extension for Caja file-manager by following [my method](https://askubuntu.com/a/1132783/66509). It works great with Mercurial repositories.

Currently I need to have similar file and directory emblems for Git repositories. I installed RabbitVCS for this purpose by following [my method](https://askubuntu.com/a/1149104/66509).

But I see that there is a problem with RabbitVCS on displaying emblems for Cyrillic objects inside Mercurial repositories. For such objects RabbitVCS shows extra error emblem

[image: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/emblems/emblem-rabbitvcs-error.svg]

on all Mercurial items as follows:

[image: Caja with Git and Mercurial repositories - errors on Cyrillic names]

I do not want to rename all 25 Mercurial repositories to ascii latin names.
So I need to disable Mercurial in RabbitVCS and use TortoiseHG for such *.hg* repositories. As I know that TortoiseHG allows cyrillic file-names.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to patch RabbitVCS files to remove all mentions of Mercurial.

For anyone interested there is a [special PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Enrbrtx/+archive/ubuntu/rabbitvcs-nohg) with patched packages.
To install them on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or Ubuntu 18.04 LTS use:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nrbrtx/rabbitvcs-nohg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-core=0.16-1nohg~ppa1 rabbitvcs-cli=0.16-1nohg~ppa1
```

With these packages the error emblems will be removed:

[image: Caja after patch]

and we can use both tools for repositories -

- RabbitVCS menus for Git (and really for SVN with Bazaar);
- TortoiseHG for Mercurial (even with Cyrillic names).

---

If you do not want to use patched packages anymore then remove them with:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:nrbrtx/rabbitvcs-nohg
```

---

Notes:

1. really it is a [bug 1840082](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1840082) in RabbitVCS Mercurial back-end. As the result the error emblems were shown and special log-file grows very fast.
2. this method was also tested on Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS - it works here too, but packages are not yet ready.